# How can I list a pivotfield with orientation xlColumnField in a specific custom order in C#

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table

I pivot on a field Sport. Assume there are 4 sports (Tennis, Baseball, Softball, Football). When the pivot table is created I want the column labels to be displayed in a custom order. How can I do that in C#.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
                    Excel.PivotField pf = (Excel.PivotField)pvtTable.PivotFields("Sport");
                //Desired list order.
                List<string> oListOrder = new List<string>() { "Football", "Tennis", "Baseball", "Softball" };  
                foreach (Excel.PivotItem pi in pf.PivotItems()) {
                    //Get index in desired list order.
                    int idx = oColumnSort.IndexOf(pi.Name); 
                    //If PivotItem in ordered list set PivotItem position to that of list. 
                    //Add 1 bc Position & List have different starting base.
                    if (idx >= 0) pi.Position = idx + 1;
                }
```